dropdown menu wordpress - Bedrock / sage
I'm trying to display the menu in the custom template of wordpress, i used to display the menu this code :
    <!-- Headerbar End -->
    @if (has_nav_menu('primary_navigation'))
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-white navbar-light sticky-top px-4 px-lg-5">
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center">
            <h1 class="m-0">{!! $siteName !!}</h1>
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler me-0" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto p-4 p-lg-0">
            {!! wp_nav_menu(['theme_location' => 'primary_navigation','container' => 'div','container_class' => 'menu-header-container', 'menu_class' => 'nav', 'echo' => false]) !!}
            <!-- Search Bar -->
                <div class="position-relative search-bar">
                    <input class="form-control bg-transparent w-100 py-3 ps-4 pe-5 " type="text" placeholder="Search ...">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary py-2 position-absolute top-0 end-0 mt-2 me-2"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Search icon -->
            <div class="border-start ps-4 d-none d-lg-block">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm p-0 toggle-search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    @endif

the menu is successfly displayed, but i encountred a problem that is when i'm trying to add pages to a dropdown menu, i discovred the menu doesnt work well as in the picture : https://imgur.com/a/L5nP5ZO
i discovered that the wp_nav_menu function is working with the   tags, in other side the dropdown menu is with   tags, code source:

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-white navbar-light sticky-top px-4 px-lg-5">
    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center">
        <h1 class="m-0">Title</h1>
    </a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler me-0" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto p-4 p-lg-0">
            <a href="index.html" class="nav-item nav-link active">Home</a>
            <a href="about.html" class="nav-item nav-link">About</a>
            <a href="service.html" class="nav-item nav-link">Services</a>
            <a href="product.html" class="nav-item nav-link">Products</a>
            <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Pages</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu bg-light m-0">
                    <a href="gallery.html" class="dropdown-item">Gallery</a>
                    <a href="feature.html" class="dropdown-item">Features</a>
                    <a href="team.html" class="dropdown-item">Our Team</a>
                    <a href="testimonial.html" class="dropdown-item">Testimonial</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="contact.html" class="nav-item nav-link">Contact</a>
            <!-- Search Bar -->
    


            <div class="position-relative w-100 search-bar" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <input class="form-control bg-transparent w-100 py-3 ps-4 pe-5 " type="text" placeholder="Search ...">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary py-2 position-absolute top-0 end-0 mt-2 me-2"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="border-start ps-4 d-none d-lg-block">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm p-0 toggle-search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

**PLEASE NOTE! THAT I'M USING BEDROCK AND SAGE **
i thought the wp_nav_menu function is working with the same structure.
